# Shehecheyanu on hand-me-downs?

Tags: halacha, blessing, clothing, shehecheyanu

If someone gets hand-me-down clothing in good condition, of the type that shehecheyanu is generally said when new, should they say it on this new-to-them garment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this article:](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/06/23/shehecheyanu-on-new-clothes-which-clothes/)

> Authorities dispute whether the berachah of shehecheyahu is entirely
>   subjective, depending on the subjective joy a person feels, or whether
>   the berachah includes an objective element, whereby if a garment or
>   item is not important, and does not usually induce joy, one cannot
>   recite the blessing.
>
> According to the Rosh, the Radvaz, and the Shulchan Aruch (223:6), a
>   poor person, who experiences joy in purchasing simple items like shoes
>   and socks, should make the blessing.
>
> However, according to Tosafos (Berachos 59b) it appears that one does
>   not make shehecheyahu on something that is not objectively important,
>   and this is the opinion of many poskim, including the Terumas Hadeshen
>   and the Rema (223:6), the Rema adding that this is the custom. This
>   ruling is also stated in the Mishnah Berurah (223:24).
>
> However, this does not mean that one can only make a shehecheyanu on a
>   very important item of clothing, that everybody will experience joy
>   from. Even if the item has some degree of importance, such as a fancy
>   shirt, it is sufficient for making the blessing, provided that the
>   person experiences subjective joy in buying it. Only on clearly
>   unimportant clothes, such as socks and underwear, or simple shirts and
>   the like, would one not make the blessing even when experiencing
>   subjective joy (instead, one should thank Hashem in one’s own words,
>   or say the blessing without mentioned the Name of Hashem).

The article does not address donations and seems to mention purchases rather than donations. However, the focus of the article seems to indicate that if one experiences joy on receiving the new item, and assuming that the gift is not underwear, socks, etc., I infer that that person should recite "Shehechiyanu". Personally, while I am not great at remembering to say "shehechiyanu" on a new coat that I purchased with my own money, (I have to take those memory pills, if only I can recall where I hid them!) but, if someone gave me a free suit (that fits well!), I would be VERY happy about that!