# The blessing שהחינו‎ for a new wrist watch?

Tags: halacha, blessing, time, jewelry, shehecheyanu

If you acquire a new wrist watch, do you make the blessing Sheheheyyanu?

Comment: expensive?...........

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to a [related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45758/shehecheyanu-on-hand-me-downs/45761#45761).

In summary, if your watch gives you personal joy, according to many opinions, you should say Shehechiyanu. If the new watch makes you more punctual to appointments when you were chronically late, then, perhaps your friends should also say "Hatov Vehamaitiv" :-) :-)