# Wearing a new watch in the nine days

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, nine-days, simchah-joy-happiness

What do the sources have to say about wearing a new watch in the nine days?

- Is it considered like significant new clothes and therefore not
  permitted
- does this minhag not apply to a time-piece
- or does it depend, as I imagine, on the degree of pleasure I get from
  wearing it?

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47531

Comment: Is your concern the blessing of shehechiyanu on new vessels? Something else?

Answer (score 3):

The Igros Moshe [OC 3:82](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=389) says that bringing new furniture into a house is not allowed, since it’s a Simcha. He says just like wearing new clothes is prohibited due to simcha (as per the M”A) so too furniture which is meant to decorate or beautify the house is assur. The issur is not limited to clothes per se.

Based on this, a new piece of jewelry that brings simcha would be assur as well.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to all three questions is Yes. The Pninei Halacha writes the Halachot of Shehechiyanu:

> ואף על בגד רגיל, כדוגמת חולצה נאה, כל ששמח בה מברך. ואפילו מי שכבר
>   יש לו חולצות רבות, אם קנה חדשה או קיבלה במתנה, והוא שמח בה, יברך
>   'שהחיינו'. ואפילו אם קנה או קיבל במתנה בגד משומש, אם הוא בגד שאנשים
>   מתכבדים בו, והוא שמח בו, יברך 'שהחיינו'. וכן הדין לגבי כלי אוכל,
>   תכשיטים וכיוצא בהם (שו"ע רכג, ג)

So like if you were to buy a cheap Timex because you need to tell the time for business etc, but it doesn't make you happy, you would not make a Shehechiyanu on it and you could wear it during the 9 days. But if it were a Rolex that makes you happy, you would make a shehechiyanu on it and would have to wait until after Tisha Ba'av.

Comment: Shehechiyanu is on buying it, not wearing it.

Comment: Are there sources who argue on the Pninei Halacha? Are they incorrect?

Comment: על בגד חדש אפשר לברך מיד בעת קנייתו, ואפשר לדחות את הברכה למועד לבישתו הראשונה. ואם בעת הקנייה הבגד אינו ראוי לשימוש, מפני שצריך לתקנו או להוסיף בו דבר, יש לדחות את הברכה למועד לבישתו הראשונה, שאז שמחים בו. ובפועל, גם כשהבגד מוכן ללבישה, נוהגים לברך עליו בעת הלבישה הראשונה (שו"ע רכג, ד; מ"ב יז; כה"ח ל).

The minhag is to not make a shehechiyanu during the 9 days.

As for whether anyone argues with the Pninei Halacha, the source is the Shulchan Aruch.