# Buying Second Hand Clothing in aveilut

Tags: clothing, mourning-aveilus, shehecheyanu

During Shloshim (and 12 months in the case of a death of a parent) one should not [buy](http://dinonline.org/2017/12/18/buying-items-for-the-home-during-shloshim-for-a-parent/) (though some specify "[wear](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/thirty-days-mourning-shloshim/)") "new" clothing (according to the summary of laws I have from my rabbi).

Does this rule of "new" clothing connect to the rules regarding saying a shehechyanu on new clothing? (related [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84318/what-is-considered-new-clothing-for-purposes-of-saying-shehechiyanu) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45758/shehecheyanu-on-hand-me-downs)).

If not, can one buy (and then wear) used clothing during the shloshim or, after the death of a parent, during the 12 months after the loss? This is speaking of clothing that one would say a shehechyanu for were they new ("[important](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/shehecheyanu/)" clothing).

Comment: I recommend removing the whole second hand business and just ask if the rule you heard about regarding buying new clothes was intended for (and based on) only purchases which would warrant a shehechiyanu or if it applies to all purchases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding second-hand new clothing after שלושים, Reb Moshe writes (אגרות משה יו"ד חלק ד' סי' ס"א אות י"ח) that since after *shloshim* it is only a *minhag*, the *issur* should really only be for things that are newly made.

However, if one gets huge pleasure "שמחה גדולה" out of finding "just what I"m looking for", it should not be worn , even though it may be bought.

If the pleasure is only because he found a bargin, then it would be permitted to buy and even tailor it to size.

Comment: From your recent questions it seems that you, or someone close to you is in avilus. המקום ינחם אתכם בתוך שאר אבילי ציון וירושלים